# Tools to Generate an Ontology from a Database Schema and Content

Tags: database, ontology

Is there a tool that can infer an ontology from information contained in both a database schema and the content in that schema? Let's say that there are tables in the database defining the following:

- The types of entities that can exist
- Instances of those entities linked to type
- The types of relationships that can exist
- Instances of those relationships linked to type and the entities concerned

I feel that looking at the schema alone is going to give a much more general ontology than I would like.

Answer (score 1):

Reveltyix has a partnership with Global IDs, a data goveranance and MDM.  One of GID's data profiling tool can export RDF to us to boot strap up a good portion of the ontology, even when that spans multiple databases.  The Revelytix technologies then use the resultant ontology to federate data and manage distributed information sources, without having to move the date.

Good Luck
Greg
201-232-9195